# How do I fix the white space on my footer in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day to you all,Please can anyone help me with this problem ? I am new to front end and over sometime now I have been trying to fix the white spaces below my footer in mobile view with resources on this site but I couldn't get any that works with it. I will be grateful if anyone can help me with this

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');


  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //Toggle Nav
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    //Animate links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = '';

      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 1}s`;
      }
    });
    //Burger Animation
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
  document.querySelectorAll('ul.nav-links li').forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('ul.nav-links').classList.remove('nav-active');
  }));
}


navSlide();

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  // get the form elements defined in your form HTML above

  var form = document.getElementById("my-form");
  //var button = document.getElementById("my-form-button");
  var status = document.getElementById("satus");

  // Success and Error functions for after the form is submitted

  function success() {
    form.reset();
    status.classList.add('success');
    status.innerHTML = "Thanks!";
  }

  function error() {
    status.classList.add('error');
    status.innerHTML = "Oops! There was a problem.";
  }

  // handle the form submission event

  form.addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData(form);
    ajax(form.method, form.action, data, success, error);
  });
});

// helper function for sending an AJAX request

function ajax(method, url, data, success, error) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) return;
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      success(xhr.response, xhr.responseType);
    } else {
      error(xhr.status, xhr.response, xhr.responseType);
    }
  };
  xhr.send(data);
}
```

```css
/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  h6 {
    font-family: silka;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
  .contact-us h3 {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}

img {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

body {
  background: #ffffff;
}

form {
  max-width: 70.5%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.feedback-input {
  color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  line-height: 11px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #220077;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  padding: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
}

.feedback-input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #220077;
}

textarea {
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150%;
  resize: vertical;
}

[type="submit"] {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 50%;
  background: #220077;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top: -4px;
  font-weight: 350;
}

[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #007722;
}

.foot {
  font-family: silka;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.fab {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.fab:hover {
  background-color: #007722;
  ;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fa-linkedin-in {
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fa-github {
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
  font-family: silka;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #007722;
}

footer .a {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Fontawesome -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/50d8f330a2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#container-frames">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact-us">Get in touch</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section class="intro">

    <h1>Let's find the solution that best fits you...</h1>

  </section>

  <section class=portfolio>
    <p>Hello, I'm David, a designer and developer from Lagos. My dream is to build solutions for global problem, while providing for young people a place to learn and explore their naturally creative side. </p>
  </section>

  <a name="container-frames"></a>
  <div class="container-frames">
    <h6>Selected works</h6>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="https://532services.ng" target="_blank">
        <img src="532serv.jpg" height="188" alt="ecommerce"></a>
      <h5>Preorder site</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgmcHhJeK0Xow14h3ARPShMs_Ado?e=e4Yp1c" target="_blank">
        <img src="ttsunity.jpg" height="188" alt="ecommerce"></a>
      <h5>Mobile game APK</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="https://www.figma.com/files/recent" target="_blank">
        <img src="Lambdap.png" height="188" alt="design"></a>
      <h5>UI designs</h5>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a name="contact-us"></a>
  <section class="contact-us">
    <h3>Get in touch</h3>
    <form action="https://formspree.io/f/xnqorqrg" method="POST" id="my-form">
      <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" />
      <input name="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" />
      <textarea name="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
      <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
    <div id="status"></div>
  </section>
</div>

<footer>
  <a href="https://web.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1412559194" target="_blank" class="fab fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="https://github.com/davidbankys" target="_blank" class="fab fa-github"></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/davidbankys" target="_blank" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/david-abel-bb222b78/" target="_blank" class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></a>
  <p class="foot">&copy;2021 - David B. Abel</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: please use a runnable snippet `<>` or `Ctrl + M` instead of posting 3 single code fragments

Comment: really don't know how to do that ... let me try

Comment: Also not to be minimal and reproducable. Giving us nearly 600 lines of code, alone 477 lines of CSS is more then just excessive. Cut it down to the minimal aprt that still reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am new to these, I am just learning

Comment: By allowing the footer to choose its own height. `20vh` can mean a lot of different things on a lot of different screens.

Comment: I've removed it, and its still the same.

Comment: There is no space after the green footer in all views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in your css (height: 265vh is to much):

```css
.nav-links {
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Try to set lower height like me above.

If you want to have nav all the time on your page try to change `position: absolute` to fixed

```css
.nav-links {
   position: fixed;
}
```